# iOS Swift Background Location Monitoring

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, background-process

I’m writing an app with background location support.  The app need to track user location points as they drive through towns on delivery routes.

I use startUpdatingLocation() from CLLocationManager, and everything works fine until the app has been in the background about 15 minutes.

The app then seems to terminate and tracking ends.

I know this continuous tracking (i.e MapMyRun) has to work, but I’m stumped as to how.

Edit: LocationManager configured as follows

```
self.locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
self.locationManager?.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
self.locationManager?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
self.locationManager?.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
self.locationManager?.activityType = CLActivityType.automotiveNavigation
self.locationManager?.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should edit your question to show the relevant code (ie. how you configure your location manager) so that we can help you.

Comment: What background modes are specified in your info.plist?

Comment: @Paulw11 edits made. On their app. Looks a little wonky on here.

Comment: @AshleyMills just “location”

Comment: You need to set [allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620568-allowsbackgroundlocationupdates) to `true`

Comment: @Paulw11 I believe I did and forgot to mention, but I will double check. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: It helps if you edit your question and paste in *your actual code* showing which function it is in. It is better to post too much code than too little.

Comment: @Paulw11 I’ll edit again. Thanks.

Comment: @Paulw11 I’ve added some additional code.

Comment: Where are you executing this code?  Which function?

Comment: @Paulw11 I have a Start button that calls a function to set up the location manager and start the updates. It’s in one one my View Controllers. Not in the appdelegate, if that helps.

Comment: You don't want to hold a reference to your location manager in a view controller associated it will be released if the view controller is released.

Comment: @Paulw11 oh! Where is a good spot then?

Comment: Your app delegate is a good spot as it exists as long as your app exists and it is easy to refer to. What work are you doing in your location delegate?  If you execute too long in the background iOS will terminate your app.

Comment: @Paulw11 I’m storing the location data in a SQLLite table and posting to a REST service when there is a network connection. Happens every two seconds or so. Until about 15 minutes in the background, and then it just terminates.

Comment: @JaredBarden Did you resolve it? If yes can you post how you did it.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the location updates to work in the background you need to enable the Background Mode capability for your app.

If you don't do that the app will terminate in the background after an X amount of time the OS thinks is appropriate.

In order to do that Click on your target, go to the capabilities Tab, enable the Background Modes and Tick the location updates. See the screenshot for more details

[image: BG Modes]

Try that and if it is still not working I suggest you upload your location manager code somewhere to take a look.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Jared, are you sure you app doesn't crash in the Background after 15 mins? Do you have any crash report systems implemented that you can track that? Something like Crashlytics might help you to see if any crashes occur. It might also help if you can post your whole code somewhere to take a look and help. 
One last thing, check if your app due to saving your location localy, consumes too much CPU and memory and is terminated by the OS for that reason.

Comment: I’m using TestFlight and don’t see any crash logs. How do I know what level of CPU and memory usage is too much?

Comment: You can override the didReceiveMemoryWarning and log that somewhere. And also try your app connected to the XCode for a long period of time and see how much you consume. I would advise adding Crashlytics to track crash reports, I've found it has better insights and reports.

Comment: I’ll take a look at those. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

iOS kills location service in background.
You need to set it manually in iPhone settings.

**To enable access, tap Settings > Location and select Always**

You can show an alert to inform the user and go to settings.

```
func checkUsersLocationServicesAuthorization(){
        /// Check if user has authorized Total Plus to use Location Services
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
            case .notDetermined:
                // Request when-in-use authorization initially
                // This is the first and the ONLY time you will be able to ask the user for permission
                self.locationManager.delegate = self
                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                break

            case .restricted, .denied:
                // Disable location features
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Allow Location Access", message: "MyApp needs access to your location. Turn on Location Services in your device settings.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

                // Button to Open Settings
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { action in
                    guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else {
                        return
                    }
                    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
                        UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                            print("Settings opened: \(success)")
                        })
                    }
                }))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                break

            case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
                // Enable features that require location services here.
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Allow Location Access", message: "Lookout does not have access to your location while in the background. To enable access, tap Settings > Location and select Always", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

                // Button to Open Settings
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { action in
                    guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else {
                        return
                    }
                    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
                        UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                            print("Settings opened: \(success)")
                        })
                    }
                }))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Not Now", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                break
            }
        }
    }
```

For more accuracy call this method too

```
func startLocationService(){
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true
}
```

And don't forget to enable Background Modes in Target -> signing and
capabilites

last check is to add permission in info.plist

That's all you have to do for live location in background

Answer (score -1):

The location updates your app gets while in the background is completely handled by iOS and out of your apps control.

According to Apple's documentation regarding background location services:

> Enabling this mode does not prevent the system from suspending the
>   app, but it does tell the system that it should wake up the app
>   whenever there is new location data to deliver. Thus, this key
>   effectively lets the app run in the background to process location
>   updates whenever they occur.

For more information refer to [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Comment: There must be some way. Apps like Google Maps don’t get terminated like what I’m seeing.

Answer (score -1):

When building a feature that required long-running background location, I encountered the same problem as the OP that background location would be maintained for a while, but shutdown after a seemingly arbitrary amount of time (15 minutes to a few hours).

(To be clear, by "background", I mean that the app is not showing on the screen, but that the user has not closed it completely.)

First, I'll list some necessary, but not sufficient, prerequisites for this to work at all:

- You do need to enable "Location Updates" in the app background capabilities and locationManager.allowBackgroundLocationUpdates to true.
- You need to obtain "when in use" authorization (note that "always" authorization is NOT required for this use case)

However, even with these in place, I've inferred that iOS will shut down your location updates if your app is doing too much processing or using too much memory or some combination of those. I was able to get location to update indefinitely (as far as I can tell, so far) by shutting almost everything down when the app goes to the background and making sure that the location updates trigger a very minimal amount of processing.

This means the only thing doing any work when my app is in the background is one very lightweight `CLLocationManagerDelegate` (called `LocationRecorder`). All this object does is receive latitude/longitude updates and store them in an array so they're available when app returns to the foreground.

Things to consider:

- I don't create `CoreData` objects in the background. `LocationRecorder` simply receives `CLLocation` points and stores them in an array of very minimalistic objects (all they have are lat, lon, time, and sequence number fields).
- I had to shut down any other `CLLocationManagerDelegates`. For example, I have a view model that receives location updates and maintains a list of parks and maps nearby the user. This is shut down when the app goes to background.
- For reasons I don't understand, iOS seems to keep doing view updates while the app is in the background. If your location updates are  triggering view updates, this will cause location updates to be shut  down. And since I am displaying the user's routes on a map, of course location updates trigger view updates!

  I got around this by creating `LocationGateway` observable objects. These gateways listen to updates on my always-running LocationRecorder and publish them for use by the view. (I also put any view-specific manipulation or filtering in these classes.) When the app goes to the background, I shut these down.

Here's the basic structure of that:

```
class LocationRecorderGateway : ObservableObject {

    @Published var waypoints = [LocationRecorder.WaypointLocation]()

    private var receiver: AnyCancellable? = nil

    private let locationRecorder = LocationRecorder.shared()

    // start() and stop() should be called when the app goes to background/comes back
    // to foreground
    func start() {
    
        // Do one initial updates when the app wakes up, then set up listener for
        // future updates.
        self.updateWaypoints()
    
        receiver = locationRecorder.$waypoints.sink { [weak self] waypoints in
            if let self {
                self.updateWaypoints()
            }
        }
    }

    func stop() {
        receiver?.cancel()
    }

    private let updatingWaypoints = NSLock()

    func updateWaypoints() {
    
        // Do any processing needed here. You might also consider keeping track of how many
        // waypoints you already processed and only process "new" ones instead of injesting
        // the entire list every time

        // If this method is long-running, you may want to run it asynchronously. If so, and
        // you're using any state variables, you may need to use an NSLock().
        waypoints = self.locationRecorder.waypoints
    
   }
}
```

Again, this is what empirically worked for me to solve this problem. I'm a little surprised this is how it's "supposed" to work and would love someone with some iOS knowledge to confirm or clarify!

Answer (score -2):

Check out

```
CLLocationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

[The Apple documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati)

Comment: The problem with significant location monitoring is I need very detailed information. That only captures every 500 meters or so.

Comment: The idea of the answer was that your app still runs in background, so you can keep monitoring the location. We were doing that in iOS 9, and checking for user's location every half a minute or so, and the app was live in AppStore. Not sure if something changed recently.